# Unable to connect from remote machine

Tags: c#, connection, tcpclient, tcplistener

I have some kind of problem and I can't check this at home if its working or not.
Here is the code

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading;
using System.IO;
using System.Net.Security;

class Program
{
    private static IPAddress ipAddress = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");
    private static int port = 6000;
    private static string data = null;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(receiveThread));
        thread.Start();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public static void receiveThread()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            TcpListener tcpListener = new TcpListener(ipAddress, port);
            tcpListener.Start();

            Console.WriteLine("Waiting for connection...");

            TcpClient tcpClient = tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient();

            Console.WriteLine("Connected with {0}", tcpClient.Client.RemoteEndPoint);

            while (!(tcpClient.Client.Poll(20, SelectMode.SelectRead)))
            {
                NetworkStream networkStream = tcpClient.GetStream();
                StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(networkStream);

                data = streamReader.ReadLine();

                if(data != null)
                    Console.WriteLine("Received message: {0}", data);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Dissconnected...\n");
            tcpListener.Stop();
        }
    }
}
```

I have a simple program as well to connect to this and then send a string with data. It works fine on localhost but there is a problem when I'm trying to connect with a different coputer.

I even turned off the firewall on my PC and router, as I did on my friend's laptop. Every time I have tried to connect, his computer refused connection. Maybe I'm doing something wrong?

Of course, `ipAddress` is a local address now since it's only working with that at the moment. Any suggestions what to do?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to set it to accept connections from any IP, there is an IPAddress overload function for this:

```
System.Net.IPAddress.Any
```

use it instead of 127.0.0.1 and it will fix your problem.

Answer (score 4):

You're listening on 127.0.0.1 which is the loopback address which is a special address that means 'this computer'. This means that you will only accept connections that are made on the same machine as the server is running on.

You need to listen on one (or more) of the server's real ip addresses.

Comment: So I should use there "my internet" ip to listen for an incoming connections ?

Comment: You could use IPAddress.Any to listen on ALL of your interfaces or the address of one particular interface to listen JUST on that interface. If you need to listen on several of your interfaces but not all then you need one listener per address.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that the setting an IP address explicitly when you initialize the TcpListener will only allow it to accept connections from **that address**. Therefore, putting in the local address of 127.0.0.1 will only accept connections originating from your PC.

The implementation you want to use is as follows:

```
TcpListener tcpListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, port);
```

This will allows connections from any IP address to connect to your program on the specified port.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is your computer (the server) that refuses to connect because 127.0.0.1 is local(-only).

Try this simple overload:

```
  TcpListener tcpListener = new TcpListener(port);
```

Comment: It is said that this method has been deprecated. I used a localhost ip since Im listening on my computer for incoming connection. I think it should work as it is, or am I wrong ?

Comment: 127001 is only your PC _from_ that PC itself. You need to listen on an externally visible IP, se the IpDdress.Any answers.