# SocketException when attempting to connect with TcpClient

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, tcp, tcpclient

When I try to create a new `TcpClient` I am getting a `SocketException`, here is my code:

```
public void TcpOpenConnection()
{
    // The next line is where the exception is occurring.
    tcpClient = new TcpClient(ipAddress, port);
    connected = true;
}
```

I have checked to make sure the port is open with `netstat -a` in cmd, and I even made another function to check if the port is open:

```
public static bool PortCheck(int port)
{
    bool portOpen = false;

    IPGlobalProperties ipGlobalProperties = IPGlobalProperties.GetIPGlobalProperties();
    TcpConnectionInformation[] tcpConnInfo = ipGlobalProperties.GetActiveTcpConnections();

    foreach (var tcpConn in tcpConnInfo)
    {
        if (tcpConn.LocalEndPoint.Port == port)
        {
            portOpen = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    return portOpen;
}
```

which returns true. The exception that I am getting is a `SocketException` and it is saying the machine I am trying to connect to is actively refusing the connection. What could be the issue here? I have also tried other ports, with no luck.

If you need more info please ask, and I will gladly supply more.

Comment: Firewall issue? Can you connect to the port using telnet?

Comment: @dman2306 Just tried allowing the port on Windows firewall with no luck.

Comment: See if you can telnet to it. If that works it's something in your code. If it doesn't its external to your code

Comment: Its seems that is not the code the problem, but how accessible is the remote host. You might also want to check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1831744/unable-to-connect-from-remote-machine

Comment: Try temporarily disabling your Windows Firewall, so you can fully rule that out.

Comment: @Todd Just disabled it and still no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The exception that I am getting is a `SocketException` and it is saying the machine I am trying to connect to is actively refusing the connection.

This is likely an indication that the target host isn't listening on the port which could be caused by a number of reasons:

- The router of the server's network is not correctly port-forwarded
- The router's firewall / server's firewall is blocking the connections
- The server and the client are not using the same port
- The server is misconfigured

The list goes on... but essentially, this error means that the server isn't allowing the connection.

Answer (score 0):

If the port is open and you try to connect to. You get SocketException because there is nothing for get the client connection.

So you need to host a Tcplistner on this port.

```
static void StartServer()
{
    int port = 150;

    TcpListener listner = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, port);
    listner.Start();
    // This line waits the client connection.
    TcpClient remote_client = listner.AcceptTcpClient();

    // do something with remote_client.
}
```

And you can connect to.

```
static void StartClient()
{
   int port = 150;
   IPAddress ip = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");

   TcpClient client = new TcpClient();
   client.Connect(ip, port);

   // Do something with client.
}
```